# findByIdAndRemove resulting in an Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can anyone please help spot why the mongoose findByIdAndRemove in the delete route below...

```
//DELETE Route
app.delete("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
  //Destroy blog
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/blogs");
    }
  });
});
```

...generates the error below:

```
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5a6a8f967c9a190507b03433 " at path "_id" for model "Blog"",
name: "CastError",
stringValue: ""5a6a8f967c9a190507b03433 "",
kind: "ObjectId",
value: "5a6a8f967c9a190507b03433 ",
path: "_id"
```

Many thanks in anticipation of your help.

Comment: Can you check if the error still occurs for "5a6a8f967c9a190507b03433" (without the blank space in the end)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're sending a 16 character long String from the client while the method `findOneByIdAndRemove` demands an ObjectId. Doing this will eradicate the issue,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //remove it as you might already it
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

app.delete("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
  //Destroy blog
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(ObjectId(req.params.id), function(err){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/blogs");
    }
  });
});
```

Also, make sure that the `_id` is 16 character long, no spaces on either side is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @vicbyte and Nilesh Singh for your contributions.

Indeed the code was failing due to the space at the end of the id: "5a6a8f967c9a190507b03433 ". The space came from the form issuing the DELETE:

```
<form id="delete" action="/blogs/<%= blog.id %> ?_method=DELETE" Method ="POST">
  <button class = "ui red basic button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Revising the the form as below...

```
<form id="delete" action="/blogs/<%= blog.id %>?_method=DELETE" Method ="POST">
  <button class = "ui red basic button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

...cleared the error.

Answer (score 0):

use async await. For Example:

```
async function(req,res) {
  await Blog.findByIdAndRemove();
}
```